# check if api endpoint exits before send request - axios

Tags: axios, vuejs3, strapi

I have axios request in my vue application:

```
async get_banner(id:number) : Promise<any> {
    return global.axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_DOMAIN}/banners/${id}`)
}
```

it works while `banner/${id}` response exits, but I have situation when I should disable banner in  my admin panel so api endpoint becomes empty. (not exits) so I am getting  `Request failed with status code 404` in my vue app console.

question is how to prevent error and know if url exits or not? what is best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Explaination:

Yes, you're absolutely right. This is the default behavior of `strapi`. Whenever the response is empty it throws a `404` error. This is basically because the `findOne` method in service returns null to the controller and when the controller sends this to the [`boom`](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/migration-guide-1-to-3.html#error-handling) module it returns a `404 Not Found` error to the front end.

##### Solution:

Just override the find one method in the controller to return an empty object `{}` when the response is null.

##### Implementation

```js
// Path - yourproject/api/banner/controllers/banner.js

const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Retrieve a record.
   *
   * @return {Object}
   */

  async findOne(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;

    const entity = await strapi.services.restaurant.findOne({ id });
    // in case no entity is found, just return emtpy object here. 
    if(!entity) return {};
    
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.restaurant });
  },
};
```

##### Side Note:

There's no need to make any changes to the browser side axios implementation. You should always handle such cases in controller rather the client side.

##### Reference:

1. [Backend Customizations](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#controllers)

Comment: hi, it looks like solution, but I am new in strapi and I can't find where to put this code

Comment: You need to put this in the controller file. It should be this path`yourproject/api/banner/controllers/banner.js`

Comment: I've updated my answer with path and references where you can read in even more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell whether an API exists or not without trying it (or relying on another API to get status of the former API)

It's usually just a manner of handling the response properly. Usually this would look something like this...

```js
  getTheBanner(id){
    this.errorMessage = null; // reset message on request init
    get_banner(id)
      .then(r => {
        // handle success
        this.results = r;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        // handle error
        if (e.status === 404){
          // set error message
          this.errorMessage = "Invalid banner Id";
        }
      })
  }
```

then in your template you could have something like this

```html
<div v-if="errorMessage" class="alert danger">{errorMessage}</div>
```